# Make tooltop appear when you place the mouse on the icon

Tags: vue.js, tooltip, vuetify.js

I would like to make a tooltip appear when you place the mouse on the icon, as in the picture below, but I can't.

[image]

```
<template v-slot:item.device="{ item }">
    <v-chip class="short">
        <span>{{item.device}}</span>
        <!-- <v-icon small @click.stop v-clipboard="item.uid" v-clipboard:success="showCopySnack" @mouseover="upHere = true" @mouseleave="upHere = false">mdi-content-copy</v-icon> -->
        <v-icon small @click.stop v-clipboard="item.uid" v-clipboard:success="showCopySnack" v-b-popover.hover.top="'I am popover directive content!'">mdi-content-copy</v-icon>
        <!-- <some-component v-show="upHere">asdasd</some-component> -->
    </v-chip>
</template>
```

Comment: Try using [v-tooltip](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips)

Comment: U can use **title** prop in a div too